# Bookmarkable URL to a project in Kie-Workbench?

Tags: drools, kie-workbench, drools-kie-workbench

Is it possible to bookmark a specific project in Kie-Workbench?

Let's say I'd like to bookmark the sample Mortgages project page in Kie-Workbench:

[image]

Browser address bar contains such URL:

> http://localhost:8076/business-central/kie-wb.jsp#LibraryPerspective%7C$ProjectScreen

URL is too generic without any info about the Mortgages project.
And of course if I bookmark this URL and then try to open it again it just opens the default Kie-Workbench home screen **forcing the user to click his way back to the specific project.**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Kie-Workbench doesn't have such feature.